# How to fix regular expression in a forEach presenting different results

Tags: javascript, regex, foreach

I have a JavaScript file with a forEach that has two regular expressions that will fire depending on the if.  It does not matter which condition I put first.  One regular expression replace has the current values of the json properties, the other has the previous iterations values.

I have tried switching the if statements.  I have Removed the `if` and tried the regex one at a time.  It does not matter one regular expression seems to be using the previous loops

```
stats.forEach( (stat) => {
    if(display_detail) {

        lsm.displayString = lsm.displayString.replace(/(\d{1,4})\s([_a-zA-Z][^\0]*)\s(\()()(\))/g, lsm.count + " $2 $3$4" + lsm.detail_array.join(',') + "$5");

    } else {

        lsm.displayString = lsm.displayString.replace(/(\d{1,4})\s([_a-zA-Z][^\0]*)/g, lsm.detail_array.join(',') + " $2")

    }            
});
```

JSON element

```
{ count: 2,
  displayString: '1 POne (9)',
  detail_array: [ 9, 14 ] }
```

After full run where I expect detail ( `diplay_detail` ) I am expecting it to print like:
2 POne (9,14)

I am getting 
1 POne (9)

But if I run it through the other regular expression I get what I would expect to get:

9,14 POne ()

I am confident it runs the first loop as the displayString stored in the json shows as much.  The displayString starts at

0 POne ()

Comment: Could you edit your question to be a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

The regex is flawed for the second round... I was over complicating the issue.  I did not need to check for specifics, I can just replace the parens since I am replacing the entire string inside the parens.  This fixes it, maybe not as elegantly but it works.

```
    lsm.displayString = lsm.displayString.replace(/(\d{1,4})\s([_a-zA-Z][^\0]*)\s(\()[\(0-9,\)].*(\))/g, lsm.count + " $2 (" + lsm.detail_array.join(",") + ")");
```